# How do I create an executable in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, console-application

In earlier versions of Visual Studio console applications generated an EXE file.Now I see DLL instead. First, is there a way to generate EXE? I need the users to run this executable with parameter: `greeting.exe johnny`. I tried both in-IDE build and `dotnet build`.

Second, if this is not possible, what is the way to run the resultant dll from command line *with parameter*?

**UPDATE**. I should have mentioned that I selected `Console Application (.NET Core)`. The old-style `Console Application` still produces executable. I am using .NET Core libraries, and I would prefer to use .NET Core Application. And I *can* run it from command line `dotnet run greeting` without parameter (but in any event, I don't think that this is what I expect user to do)!

Comment: `Visual Studio console applications generated an EXE file` They still do. Check your project settings, if you are getting a DLL then you are not building a console app.

Comment: Check the "Output type" parameter in your project properties: http://imgur.com/a/hOqcw

Comment: Re latest edit: that's how .NET ***Core*** apps work. See [Creating a .NET Core Console application in just 5 minutes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/06/01/creating-a-net-core-application-in-just-5-minutes/). If you want an EXE then just build a regular .NET console app.

Comment: thank you, dxiv! Do you mind putting it as an answer that I can accept? Also, I was banging my head trying to run `dotnet run greetings.dll johnny` when the correct command is `dotnet greetings.dll johnny` (without *run*)

Comment: Thanks, but mine was just a link in a comment. Feel free to elaborate it and post your own full answer.

Comment: as you wish :) for me it was a perfect answer, and a link for more info!

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have picked the wrong project type. The right type is somewhat similar to "Win Console Application". It seems like you selected a (portable) class library.

If you pick the right project type, your exe file will be in the `Debug` folder of your project once you hit "Run".

Update: Since the question has been updated, an update to my answer:

If you select for example **Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Console Application**, it will definitely create an exe file. You don't need to select ASP.NET core or anything similar. A simple Visual C# Console application should do the job.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question to make it clear which project I selected

Comment: Yes, thank you, you are correct - but my question was how *do* I create a .NET Core executable

Comment: Oh sorry, this was not clear to me before the update. Then you should probably go with the comment on your question.